# Flask doesn't get secret_key config from config object

Tags: python, flask

I have a config class that has the config for my Flask app.  Most of the config options are picked up, but the `secret_key` remains unset, and so using the session raises an error.  Why isn't the config fully imported?

`app.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.BaseConfig')
```

`config.py`:

```
class BaseConfig(object):
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///test.db'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    secret_key = '122332'
```

When I access a view that uses the session, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: the session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Config keys are all uppercase, to distinguish between config and other attributes on whatever object is being scanned.  The key `secret_key` is lower case, so it's not picked up.

```
SECRET_KEY = 'stack overflow'
```